# parsing constant using Complex (curly) syntax in double quote

Tags: php

i am unable to get concept of  using Complex (curly) syntax in double quote -

```
class beers {
    const softdrink = 'rootbeer';
    public static $ale = 'ipa';
}

define('TEST_DATA','test');
$test='hello';

$rootbeer = 'A & W';
$ipa = 'Alexander Keith\'s';

//This works; outputs: I'd like an A & W
echo "I'd like an ${beers::softdrink}\n";

//This works too; outputs: I'd like an Alexander Keith's
echo "I'd like an ${beers::$ale}\n";

//but this not work
echo "I'd like an ${TEST_DATA}\n";
```

`${TEST_DATA}` is not working in case of constant but in case of class constant `${beers::softdrink}` its working.

Comment: well, a constant isn't a string. Just concatenate and you'll be good; `echo 'whatever ' . TEST_DATA . ' foobar';`

Comment: @giorgio its  {${TEST_DATA}} work, but ${TEST_DATA}  does not.

Comment: Its much like the [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) syntax , your just using an object as the name reference, whats the question?

Answer (score 0):

This can achieved using small hack

```
<?php 
class beers {
    const softdrink = 'rootbeer';
    public static $ale = 'ipa';
}

// hack declaration
function _expr($v) { return $v; }
$_expr = '_expr';

define('TEST_DATA','test');
$test='hello';


$rootbeer = 'A & W';
$ipa = 'Alexander Keith\'s';

//This works; outputs: I'd like an A & W
echo "I'd like an ${beers::softdrink}\n";

//This works too; outputs: I'd like an Alexander Keith's
echo "I'd like an ${beers::$ale}\n";

//this should work
echo "I'd like an ${$_expr(TEST_DATA)} \n";

//This works; outputs: I'd like an A & W
echo "I'd like an ${$_expr(beers::softdrink)}\n";

?>
```

It should print following

I'd like an A & W

I'd like an Alexander Keith's

I'd like an I'd like an hello

I'd like an A & W

for more details
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php